# only number validation code in vb.net

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

only number validation code in vb.net  i have used this code but when i want to update it the code doesn't allow me to change or delete the number it doesn't even allows backspace button to work what changes can i make ??? to update the mobile no i m using sql server database

```
Private Sub txtcustcontact_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As          System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtcustcontact.KeyPress
    If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
        Tip.Show("Enter Numeric Value Only ", sender)
        e.KeyChar = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try as below:

```
Private Sub  txtcustcontact_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtcustcontact.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 13 AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Numeric values only")
            e.Handled = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank u so much it worked i had one more issue i wanted to search a row according to name as in a search textbox takes a name and the gridview should show the values according to the name by filtering all the values of database what code should i use for it

Comment: welcome @Malishka , please mark as answer as it worked for you, also for searching you can fetch value of textbox and make a query in your database to search in database.